# get Height of Next img in Rhinoslider

Tags: jquery, slider, rhino

I'm using Rhinoslider on my site, the used images have different sizes and I want the slider to adapt to each Image height.

The slider markup is like this:

## #Slider

- .rhino-item

  - img
- .rhino-item .rhino-active

  - img
- .rhino-item

  - img

I'm calling a function if you click the next button

```
var ImageHeight = $('.rhino-active').next('.rhino-item').next('img').outerHeight();
// alert( ImageHeight );
$('#Slider').css('height', ImageHeight);
```

I also tried

```
    var ImageHeight = $('.rhino-active').next('.rhino-item img').outerHeight();
// alert( ImageHeight );
$('#Slider').css('height', ImageHeight);
```

But the result for height is always "null" so I think the function isn't finding the img?

Can someone please help me?

Thx in advance

Comment: Hey can you create a fiddle for this,will check it. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: tried using `closest()` instead of `next()`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3VSYd/
like this?

Comment: @Gintas K: $('.rhino-active').closest('.rhino-item img').outerHeight(); also returns "null"

Comment: and what does `$('.rhino-active').closest('.rhino-item img').height();` returns? also null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:
$('.rhino-active').next('.rhino-item').children('img').height();